# Building osmo-qcdiag on Ubuntu 16.04 with libosmocore and libqmi

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, make, modem-manager, diagnostic

I am trying to get osmo-qcdiag to build (Project : https://osmocom.org/projects/osmo-qcdiag/repository), but I am getting errors with libosmocore which I built successfully, but unfortunately osmo-qcdiag wont build. Here is the make output:

```
    cc -g  -O0 -Wall `pkg-config --cflags libosmocore` `pkg-config --cflags qmi-glib` -o osmo-qcdiag-log diagchar_hdlc.o diag_io.o osmo-qcdiag-log.o diag_msg.o protocol.o diag_cmd.o gprs_l1.c gprs_rlc.o gprs_mac.o diag_gsm.o diag_log.o diag_log_gsm.o diag_log_gprs.o diag_log_wcdma.o diag_log_umts.o diag_log_qmi.o diag_dpl.o diag_log_simcard.o diag_event.o `pkg-config --libs libosmocore` `pkg-config --libs qmi-glib`
diagchar_hdlc.o: In function `osmo_crc16_ccitt_byte':
/usr/include/osmocom/core/crc16.h:42: undefined reference to `osmo_crc16_ccitt_table'
diagchar_hdlc.o: In function `crc_check':
/home/ahmed/Downloads/Tx/Worki/osmo-qcdiag/src/diagchar_hdlc.c:252: undefined reference to `osmo_crc16_ccitt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'osmo-qcdiag-log' failed
make: *** [osmo-qcdiag-log] Error 1
```

Can anybody please help me with this? I have tried to include different versions of libosmocore and libqmi: I even tried one in other repos, but it still fails similarly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer what works for me is that I had to use a nightly build to get things done to some extent.